# firestore is not working with next js app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I have created a next.js project and I have installed firebase using `npm i firebase` I have copied the configuration from firebase but it is not working.

I am getting the following error. I have provided a screenshot.

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { dbb } from '@/src/providers/firebase'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dbb.collection('languages').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const data = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
      });
      setData(data);
      console.log(data);
    }
    )
  }, []);
...rest
```

config.file

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const dbb = getFirestore(app);
```

[image]

Comment: TypeError: _src_providers_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.dbb.collection is not a function

getting this error now.

Comment: @SergeySosunov Hello sir. please help me to fix this error.